# Tying in unlink() with sql delete

Tags: php, delete-file, unlink

I have setup a simple while loop which returns all images in a table along with their respective title and description so that users can update the details accordingly for each image.

The images are returned with a checkbox which allows user to delete images as per php code

```
if($_POST['doDelete'] == 'Delete') {

if(!empty($_POST['u'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['u'] as $uid) {
        $id = filter($uid);
        mysql_query("delete from landscape where id='$id'");
    }
 }
 $ret = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?'.$_POST['query_str'];;

 header("Location: $ret");
 exit();
}
```

How do I incorporate the `unlink()` function into the page so that the file is also removed from the server?

Comment: Just add `unlink(foo)` after `mysql_query`?

Comment: You really should be escaping that variable in your query...

Comment: @Michael: `$id = filter($uid)` seems to be doing the trick?

Comment: @Cyclone: Possibly, not a standard library function; maybe he's aliased `mysql_real_escape_string()` to `filter()` elsewhere in his code...

Comment: @Michael: My point being, he's addressing the sanitization in his code, whether or not we can see the exact function.

Comment: @JD2011, really stop using MySQL and instead use `MySQLi` or `PDO`, they are far better and MySQL is **deprecated** as well as **insecure** . Consider researching and updating, the changes are easy to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the images are named in accordance with the ID:

```
foreach ($_POST['u'] as $uid) {
    $id = filter($uid);
    mysql_query("delete from landscape where id='$id'");
    unlink( '/path/to/images/' . $id);
}
```

Be sure to properly escape $id before using it in your query or in the unlink statement.

Comment: You forgot a `;` after your `unlink` statement

Comment: On the above code then, if the images are stored in /images/landscape/ how does it recognise the correct filename to unlink - does this have to be specified (such as using 'images/landscape/<?php echo $rrows['imagesrc'];?>'....?

Or would the following work when the radiobox is checked.

foreach ($_POST['u'] as $uid) {
    $id = filter($uid);
    mysql_query("delete from landscape where id='$id'");
    unlink( '/images/landscape/' . $id);
}

If it makes things simpler, I would be happy to post my entire code as opposed to simply a snippet as above

Thanks!

Comment: @JD2011: The snippet you posted in your comment will work if `'/images/landscape/' . $id` is a valid filename. Is it?

Comment: hmmmm - really making myself sound stupid now - the only valid filename I can think of would be the imagesrc field from the database so assuming I should use unlink( '<?php echo $rrows['imagesrc'];?>'); instead of unlink( '/images/landscape/' .$id);.....am I on the right track!?

Comment: I am not sure what `$rrows['imagesrc']` contains, because it does not appear in the snippets you posted above. However, if it contains the filename including the full path, you would use it like this: `unlink( $rrows['imagesrc'] );` There is no need to use `<?php ... ?>` because you are already within a PHP code block.

Comment: spoke too soon! The recordset $rrows isnt defined at the point in the page when this delete function is specified - assuming I enter a different mysql query just before (select * from landscape) it should do the trick...

Comment: while this answer is correct it is not the best answer, as if any error occurs within the SQL statement the file is still unlinked, another answer on this page does check that only when the SQL completes successfully does the file actually get removed.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Unlink()` with in loop like :

```
foreach ($_POST['u'] as $uid) {
    $id = filter($uid);
    if(mysql_query("delete from landscape where id='$id'")){
    unlink( '/path/to/images/' . $id);
    }
}
```

I have used `If` because if the file deleted successfully from the database only then it will be deleted from the server.
Also If you have moved the file into folder by the name of file then First get information about file from database by `$id` and then use

```
unlink( '/path/to/images/' . $file_name);
```

instead

```
unlink( '/path/to/images/' . $id);
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: IMO this is a better answer than the accepted answer.

Comment: You could also further add an `else` clause to output a `mysql_error()` statement, too

Answer (score -1):

Well, where are the files stored on the server? How are they stored? Just call `unlink` with the file path that leads to where the image is stored.

Comment: they are stored in a folder on the server /images/landscape/

I also have in mysql an imagesrc field which points to "images/landscape/1.jpg" for example so could I simply use this field to unlink....?

Sorry for my stupidity - not heard of unlink until today as previously stored images as BLOBs in the database and dont want to delete everything by mistake!!

Comment: This answer is not very helpful. It's more like a comment.